# using firstUpdate.current but don't understand how it is updating react component

Tags: reactjs, datetime, react-hooks, timer

I am working on a timer but I wanted to make sure the timer shows up right away if you do a hard refresh on the page. I tried experimenting and ended up placing these in my code. And the issue is, it works but I don't know why. Can someone explain as to how the component is updating.

```
const date = new Date();
const [time, setTime] = useState("");
const firstUpdate = useRef(true);

useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const tmpTime = setInterval(() => {
      setTime(date.toLocaleTimeString());
      // setMinutes(minutes + 1);
    }, seconds * 1000);

    
    return () => {
      clearInterval(tmpTime);
    };
  }, [time]);


return ( 
<h1>{firstUpdate.current ? date.toLocaleTimeString() : "time"}</h1>
)
```

The original code was not a "time" in h1 tag but referencing time state, I just decided to make it into a string to see what happens. And now I am more confused. I'm new to react

Answer (score 0):

Your code either uses more functionality than it actually requires or there is more happening in the parts you didn't post. A simpler version that achieves the same result is:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';


function MyApp() {
  const updatePeriodSeconds = 1;
  const [time, setTime] = useState(date.toLocaleTimeString());

  useEffect(() => {
      const tmpTime = setInterval(() => {
        setTime(date.toLocaleTimeString());
      },  updatePeriodSeconds * 1000);
      return () => clearInterval(tmpTime)
  })

  return ( 
  <h1>{time}</h1>
  )
}
```

Since you're new to react (don't worry everything will make sense after some time, this is normal), a few surprising bits might be:

1. When you want to run sth. in the background like data fetching or updating your page in regular intervals, you call the logic in `useEffect`, since your code has side effects (roughly meaning it's not simply a function that takes and input and returns an output, without touching anything else). React then finds a way to render the page smoothly.
2. Often code with side effects would create memory leaks if you don't clean it up. The function you return in useEffect is ran if your component is removed or rendered, and thus should cleanup leftovers like the interval.
3. If you have data that changes over time, you store it in a `state`, to create state/memory you can call the `useState` hook. It returns sth. similar to a pointer/reference that holds the state and a function to update it. The argument you provide, is the default/start state.

Try following the react [docs](https://react.dev/learn) and challenge yourself with their examples to improve your understanding.